# How to create a timestamp with timezone value which is (currentdate-7) days in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date, date-format

My postgresql timestamp with timezone format is 2020-07-03T07:01:42.231433+00:00

How can I create such a timestamp value which is (current date - 7 days) in nodejs?

My aim is create a grapghl query to update all rows older than 7 days in postgresql.

```
mutation MyMutation($timestampInterval: timestamptz) {
  update_Offers(where: {createdAt: {_lt: $timestampInterval}}, _set: {active: false}) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

In this query I am comparing if the createdAt time (which is timestamp with timezone) is less than the timestamp with timezone value that I am giving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use moment.js library.
its fairly easy using it.

```
const moment = require('moment');
const oldDate = moment().substract(7,'d').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss+00:00');
```